# How to check whether a class is instantiated in Python

Tags: python, class

So I'm trying to write a function to instantiate a class.
Since I am looping through said function, I need a condition so the function only instantiates the class if it has not yet been done (otherwise HP would be maxed out every loop, among other problems).
Something I tried:

```
class Fighter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.maxHP = 100
        self.HP = self.maxHP
        self.attack = 10

def before_fight():
    if fighterYOU == None:    #this is where I would like a condition that checks if fighterYOU is already instantiated. "None" does not work.
        fighterYOU = Fighter()
    fighterYOU.update()
    fight()

before_fight()
#...program continues
```

Is a check like this possible, or should I just try moving the instantiation somewhere else, where it won't be looped through?

Comment: Use `is` than `==` for `None` comparison

Comment: Please post an MCVE. This code makes it very difficult to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to avoid recreating the fighter. For this, just set the variable to None first:

```
class Fighter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.maxHP = 100
        self.HP = self.maxHP
        self.attack = 10

def before_fight():
    if fighterYOU == None:    #this is where I would like a condition that checks if fighterYOU is already instantiated. "None" does not work.
        fighterYOU = Fighter()
    fighterYOU.update()
    fight()

fighterYOU = None   # default is None

before_fight()
#...program continues
```